# Can someone help me to modify this code so it works in C# ASP.NET?

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

**The user should be able to enter student id number in the textbox at the top of the form and all the information should be shown in the grid view order.
The user should be able to click on the Return Book button to return the book**

*Note : I am not connecting to my database can someone correct this code please*

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Drawing;

namespace CHS_Online_Library.Admin 
{
  public partial class ReturnBooks: System.Web.UI.Page 
  {
    string str = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["connect"].ConnectionString;
    
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) 
    {
      dataGridView1_bookreturn.DataSource = GetBookReturnList();
    }

    private DataTable GetBookReturnList() 
    {
      DataTable dtViewBook = new DataTable();

      using(SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(str)) 
      {
        using(SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM BookReturn", con)) 
        {
          con.Open();
          SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

          dtViewBook.Load(reader);
        }
      }

      return dtViewBook;
    }

    protected void BR_Return_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
    {
      SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection();
      con.ConnectionString = "";
      SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
      cmd.Connection = con;

      try 
      {
        con.Open();
        cmd.CommandText = "insert into BookReturn(StudentID, BookName,IssueDate,ReturnDate,) values('" + textBox_brsearch.Text + "', '" + BR_bookname.Text + "', '" + BR_issuedate.Text + "', '" + dateTimePicker1.Text + "')";
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        lblRMsg.Text = "Book was return successfully";
        lblRMsg.Visible = true;
        lblRMsg.ForeColor = Color.Green;

      } catch (Exception ex) {
        lblRMsg.Text = "Try Again";
        lblRMsg.Visible = true;
        lblRMsg.ForeColor = Color.Red;

      } finally {
        con.Close();
      }
    }

    protected void textBox_brsearch_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) 
    {
      {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection();
        con.ConnectionString = "";
        con.Open();
        if (textBox_brsearch.Text != "") 
        {
          SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select BookName, IssueDate from IssueBook where StudentID =@StudentID", con);
          cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@StudentID", int.Parse(textBox_brsearch.Text));
          SqlDataReader da = cmd.ExecuteReader();
          while (da.Read()) {
            BR_bookname.Text = da.GetValue(0).ToString();
            BR_issuedate.Text = da.GetValue(1).ToString();

          }
          con.Close();
        }
      }

    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you provide some more details about what you're trying to do and what's not working? What steps have you taken to try and debug this?

Comment: Which exception do you get and where exactly? How does your conection string look like?

Comment: Only your first method uses the configured connection string, the rest sets it explicitly to an empty string

Comment: As already mentioned if you update the instances of con.ConnectionString = "" to be con.ConnectionString = str your methods will be able to connect to your database.  Also str isn't the best name for your connection string - try to use something that describes its purpose/use.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I'm right, but looking at your code and with what you explain I think this is it.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
    dataGridView1_bookreturn.DataSource = GetBookReturnList();
    dataGridView1_bookreturn.DataBind(); //you forget this part
}
```

See the [reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.databind?view=netframework-4.8#:%7E:text=Use%20the%20DataBind()%20method%20to%20bind%20data%20from%20a,a%20valid%20data%20source%20control.).